# How to emit values from different functions, but collect all of them in one place? Flow Kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin-flow, kotlin-coroutines

In my activity I need to emit different flow values on callbacks like :

```
  override fun onActivityResult(requestCode: Int, resultCode: Int, data: Intent?) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data)
    emit(1)
  }


override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
    emit(1)
}
```

and collect in another class like:

```
collect{value->
  when(value){
    1->..
    2->..
  }
}
```

is it possible?

Answer (score 1):

How about this?:

Make an interface to notify on every callback, overridden method, etc. you need:

```
interface Notifier<T> {
    fun notify(t: T)
}
```

Inside your class declare an object to implement that interface:

```
private var notifier: Notifier<Int>? = null
```

Also declare a Flow with the `callbackFlow` builder where you will initialize the notifier object:

```
val myFlow = callbackFlow<Int> {
    notifier = object: Notifier<Int> {
        override fun notify(t: Int) {
            launch {
                channel.send(t)
            }
        }
    }
    awaitClose()
}
```

Inside your methods notify your data:

```
override fun onActivityResult(requestCode: Int, resultCode: Int, data: Intent?) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data)
    notifier?.notify(1)
}


override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
    notifier?.notify(2)
}
```

And finally consume the Flow like this:

```
val job = launch(Dispatchers.Default) {
    myClassReference.myFlow
        .collect {
            when(it) {
                1 -> { println("It's one") }
                2 -> { println("It's two") }
            }
        }
}
```

And make sure to cancel `job` properly.

Comment: it just does not work, collecting nothing. Do you have  any idea why?

Comment: @NurseyitTursunkulov It's hard to know without the code but if you start collecting after the callbacks are fired then you won't collect anything.